# constraints (?) changed after using MFMessageComposeViewController, MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: swift, constraints

I have a detail view in a UISplitViewcontroller with a label "Remarks".

It's height constraint is set to <= 63, it's bottom Space is set to a UITableView below it

[image]

Remarks will be filled with text and I want to constrain it to a maximum of 3 lines (height = 21)

This works perfectly :

[image]

When the phone number is a cell phone, not only a phone is shown, but also a button to send a text message. However after showing an MFMessageComposeViewController (the same happens with MFMailComposeViewController for e-mail addresses), suddenly the Remark label is showing 4 lines :

[image]

There is not much code to show, for the sake of completeness :

to show:

```
  @objc func sendEmail (sender : AnyObject) {

    let button = sender as! ActionButton
    let viewController = button.viewController


    var picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = viewController
    picker.setToRecipients([self.address!])

    viewController!.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

and to dismiss

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I don't change anything on that storyboard view it (don't add fields or add/remove/change constraints)

Anyone an idea on how this happens and how to fix it ?

Comment: Is the text displayed in UILabel?

Comment: I don't understand your question... The remarks ("To seek out...") are displayed in a UILabel. That label has the constraints shown. I don't change the constraints, but after showing the popup sheet to send a text message (iMessage or Text) of sheet for sending a mail using MFMessageComposeViewController or MFMailComposeViewController, that UILabel suddenly shows 4 lines of text

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the UILabel's numberOfLines is changed or something, which might cause the problem. But I'm not sure if you are using UILabel or not.

Comment: Like I said, I'm using UILabel, but I do NOT change numberOfLines or the constraints in code. The only thing that is done is fire up a method from a UIButton. That method has the code described in the question : var picker = ...

Comment: Is there any warning showing in your console? I'm thinking there might be some kind of constraint conflict.

Comment: no warnings shown in console

Comment: That's kind of weird. Is the `lineBreak` property changed or something? What is it set to in storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92025/discussion-between-glenn-and-skyline75489).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something very similar. I have a UIView that sits directly under a UITableView and contains a button to send an email. If I click the button, and then pop up a compose email view using MFMailComposeViewController, then when the dialog is dismissed, it's as if the ViewController's view has increased its height by 50 pixels. I have a constraint that keeps my UIView at the bottom. I had to create a Bool that keeps track of when I return from the email view, and it changes the constraint by 50 pixels. This is the code I have in viewWillAppear, where returnFromEmail is the Bool that is set to true after I present the MFMailComposeViewController:

```
bottomViewBottomConstraint.constant = returnFromEmail ? 50 : 0
returnFromEmail = false
```